# PHP Regex for Username?

Tags: php

Hello I'm trying to parse string chars to prevent sql injection and other hacks. I don't want to use mysql_real_escape_string or other filters. I want to just use a regex and have characters A-Z 0-9 !@#$-_

I mean I could use a regex such as:

```
$newStr = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '_', $str);
```

but I just want to be safe and I'm not very good at regex. Thanks again guys, you really are awesome.

Comment: *Why* don't you want to apply proper escaping? It's probably a bad reason, and your users are gonna suffer for it.

Comment: well I'm using mysqli and don't want to use mysql. I'd have to make another database connection.

Comment: Please read the manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: @lhsan I have read the manual but I don't want to make a new database connection. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
$newStr = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '_', $str);
```

should be:

```
$newStr = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9!@#$-]/', '_', $str);
```

The code below should strip out:

> '"/\;?"

```
<?php
        $newStr = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9!@#$-]/', '_', "test\'\"\/\\\;\?");
        echo $newStr;
?>
```

Which produces:

```
test__________%
```

Comment: or even better A-Z a-z 0-9 and the chars _ and - and ! and # and $ ? lmao

Comment: @user1594121 textbox max length can always be changed, don't rely on that for limits.

Comment: Good point! Fixed the code! Thx